# Filling in a grid in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, plot

I want to achieve the following. I have a x-y plot with a function y dependent on x. The plot consists of a mesh of squares. When a function point is inside the function block, the block changes color. I have attached an example:

[image]

I want to make an simillar figure, but I want to be able to make the gridsize variable.

I know how to make a plot with plt.plot(), but I'm not familliar with making a grid and filling in that grid if the function point falls in a square. Can somebody refer to numpy or mathplotlib functions that can help?

Thanks

Comment: Map the domain to the grid. Fill in the values between min and max x in each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.histogram2d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) to create a 2D histogram and plot the locations with count greater than zero with [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Input data
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 300)
y = np.sin(x)
# Plot limits
x_min, x_max = -3, 3
y_min, y_max = -2, 2

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 3))
# First plot
resolution = 25
xg = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, resolution)
yg = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, resolution)
h, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y, (xg, yg))
plt.subplot(121)
# Transpose because imshow swaps X and Y axes
plt.imshow(h.T > 0, origin='lower', extent=(xg[0], xg[-1], yg[0], yg[-1]))
# Show grid
plt.gca().set_xticks([], minor=False)
plt.gca().set_xticks(xg, minor=True)
plt.gca().set_yticks([], minor=False)
plt.gca().set_yticks(yg, minor=True)
plt.grid(True, 'minor')
# Second plot
resolution = 50
xg = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, resolution)
yg = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, resolution)
h, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y, (xg, yg))
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(h.T > 0, origin='lower', extent=(xg[0], xg[-1], yg[0], yg[-1]))
plt.gca().set_xticks([], minor=False)
plt.gca().set_xticks(xg, minor=True)
plt.gca().set_yticks([], minor=False)
plt.gca().set_yticks(yg, minor=True)
plt.grid(True, 'minor')
# Show plot
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: Result plot]

Comment: Is it possible to make the grid visable?

Comment: @Terr070 I edited the answer to show a grid, plus a few other minor changes (e.g. using `extent` so axis are in the right scale).

Comment: you're a legend!

Answer (score 2):

here is a piece of code that should work for graphs centered around (min(X)-max(X)) and (min(Y),max(Y)) :

```
import numpy as np

def grid_plot(X,Y,resx,resy) :
 d_x=resx/(np.max(X)-np.min(X))
 d_y=resy/(np.max(Y)-np.min(Y))
 mat=np.zeros((resy,resx))
 for i in range(len(X)) :
    mat[int((Y[i]-np.min(Y))*d_y),resx-int((X[i]-np.min(X))*d_x)]=1
 return mat
```